# Trying to set a textField on top of a keyboard in swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am trying to set a textfield on top of a keyboard programmatically in swift. I am using a switch statement to determine which size screen the user is on so this will affect the size of the keyboard and where the textField should be place. My code is not running can anyone help.

I am still trying to get my head around swift.

```
 var myTextField : UITextField!
        var windowHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

        switch windowHeight {
        case 667:
            //iphone 6 and 6+
            myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: view.frame.size.height - 258.0, width: view.frame.size.width - 40, height: 40.00))
        case 568:
            //iphone 5 5s and 6zoom
            myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: view.frame.size.height - 253.0, width: view.frame.size.width - 40, height: 40.00))
        default:
            //Segue or alert view here
            println("The screen size is incorrect")
        }

        myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line

        self.view.addSubview(myTextField)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother calculating exact screen heights.
Instead just use a category that animate your view automatically.

https://github.com/lazerwalker/MWKeyboardAnimation